# How to Query Cosmos DB graph by use of SQL CONTAINS

Tags: sql, azure, graph, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Cosmo DB graph where I would like to access the 'name' field in an expression using the string matching CONTAINS in Cosmos DB. CONTAINS works at 1 level as in matching CONATINS

1. `SELECT s.label, s.name FROM s WHERE  CONTAINS(LOWER(s.name._value), "cara") AND s.label = "site"`

I also tried with a UDF function

2. `SELECT s.label, s.name FROM s WHERE(s.label = 'site' AND udf.strContains(s.name._value, '/cara/i'))`

I don't get any hits or syntax errors from Cosmos DB even that should be at least one record in this example. Does anyone have a hint? Thanks in advance

```
[
    {
        "label": "site",
        "name": [
            {
                "_value": "0315817 Caracol",
                "id": "2e2f000d-2e0a-435a-b472-75d257236558"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "site",
        "name": [
            {
                "_value": "0315861 New Times",
                "id": "48497172-1734-43d0-9866-51faf9f603ed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is a similar question to this one: [How to search JSON in depth in Azure Cosmos DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373935/how-to-search-json-in-depth-in-azure-cosmos-db)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the `name` property is an array not an object.So, you need to use `join` in sql.

```
SELECT s.label, s.name , name._value FROM s 
join name in s.name
where CONTAINS(LOWER(name._value), "cara") AND s.label = "site"
```

Output:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks is a small word, but I am really thank full. You assistance made me move forward. BR Torkil

Comment: @Torkil2908861 Great, you could mark my answer to end this question.Thank you.