# How to search JSON in depth in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have JSON files like below stored in Cosmos DB. I want to search text in activities/message.

```
{
  "id": "575858a7-f814-41fd-ae5a-6f38ba2da957",
  "name": "Test Name",
  "activities": [
    {
      "message": "activity 1.1 message",
      "messageType": "type1"
    },
    {
      "message": "activity 1.2 message",
      "messageType": "type2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I find out that I can use search like below.

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE CONTAINS(c.activities[0].message, "activity")
```

But, this can only search the first record in the array of activities. How to search all records in the array? Thanks.

Comment: can't you just omit the array operator? `c.activities.message`

Comment: I had really tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Just realise that I asked similar question like this [How to Query Cosmos DB graph by use of SQL CONTAINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944616/how-to-query-cosmos-db-graph-by-use-of-sql-contains?rq=1). Links to it for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a join on your query, so then you array will be treated as a normalized entity and then you can apply the filter.

```
select c.id, a.message
from c join a in c.activities
where CONTAINS(a.message,"activity")
```

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join)

Comment: Although it prompts an error message `'SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set.`, I can easily correct it like this.
`SELECT c.id, a.message  FROM c JOIN a IN c.activities
WHERE CONTAINS(a.message, "activity")` Thank you!

Comment: Sorry yeah, you need to specify the specific columns in this case.

Comment: I edited my initial response, so other people don't face same issue you faced. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will be just

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE CONTAINS(c.activities.message, "activity")
```